# long tcolorbox in multicols environment

Tags: tcolorbox, multicol

I need quite long areas with gray background within a multicols environment, which I would like to solve using tcolorbox. *(I already tried mdframed which has similar issues like these with tcolorbox.)*

If the boxes are longer than a column or even a page, the page breaking is not working as it should: Sometimes white space before the box (shown in this example), sometimes a page break inside the box with much white space and the rest of the box jumps to the next page.

Text is generated automatically, so manual page breaks are no option.

Any idea how to solve this would be great!
As well as other options or packages.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a5,10pt,twoside,openright]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %to use lipsum
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newenvironment{futurebox}
{\begin{tcolorbox}[%
        enhanced jigsaw, colback=light-gray,
        sharp corners, breakable, height=11cm
        %pad at break=2mm, break at=-\baselineskip/0pt
        ]}{\end{tcolorbox}} 

\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1mm}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{first chapter}
    \lipsum[1]\par
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-2]\par
    
    \begin{futurebox}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{futurebox}

    \lipsum[1-2]\par
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1 and 2 with white space]

[image: Page 3 and 4]

Comment: your linespread is too small. Remove `\linespread{0.83}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for the fast answer, but the ``\linespread`` was not the problem.
I edited the code to show that the same problem happens without it as well.

Comment: open an issue at the tcolorbox github.